# Register GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver in autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I'm trying to register the current IDependencyResolver in autofac using delegate registration

```
builder.Register(c => GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver).As<IDependencyResolver>();
builder.RegisterType<AService>();
```

So I can inject it like:

```
public class AService
{
    public AService(IDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        ...
```

The problem is that, this seems to work fine the first time AService is resolved, but the second time I get the following Autofac error:

"Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed."

If I register AService as delegate:

```
builder.Register(c => new AService(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver);
```

Everything works fine.

My guess is that the delegate registration for GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver returns the same instance every time, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Is there a way to register this global dependency resolver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you'll need to use something like this:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver).As<IDependencyResolver>().ExternallyOwned().SingleInstance()
```

It's a good idea in general to specify desired lifetime explicitly when registering your stuff (and someone else's too :))

Comment: that ExternallyOwned method was the missing piece. Thanks!